# Standard terminology for node in tree with multiple children

Tags: set-theory, terminology, trees

Is there a standard terminology for a node in a tree that has multiple children?

For instance, in describing in perfect tree in $\omega^{< \omega}$ how would you describe the nodes that are extended by multiple incompatible elements?   I feel like I should know this, but neither google nor bing were helpful.

Comment: They are often referred to as splitting nodes, but what exactly constitutes a splitting node often depends on the context. For example one might ask that the node has infinitely many children, etc...

Comment: Right, perfect, that's exactly what I needed (in my context splitting means exactly that...though it's also true that any node which splits has infinitely many children).  Do you want to submit that as an answer so I can accept it or should I?

Comment: I've seen: infinitely-splitting, $\infty$-splitting, $n$-splitting, ${\geq}n$-splitting, ${<}n$-splitting, etc., with the obvious semantics. Usually, this means the splitting happens "right away" rather than "some point later".